# Configure Python3 from source so that it can be used across Linux distros

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, environment-variables, configure

I am looking to build Python3 from source code by following simple steps:

```
> wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/Python-3.8.3.tgz
> tar xzf Python-3.8.3.tgz
> cd Python-3.8.3
> ./configure --prefix=/opt/install38 --exec-prefix=/opt/install38
> make -j8
> make install
```

This successfully installs the python in `/opt/install38/bin` directory and copies libraries in `/opt/install38/lib` directory.

The idea is to ship this installation so that there aren't any version or some other installation dependencies. However when I used this installation in some other machine, I got following error:

```
> cd install38/bin
> ./python3.8
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = './python'
....
....
```

This error can be resolved by using setting environment variable `PYTHONHOME=..`, by doing so python binary can load libraries from `install38/lib` directory.

Can we somehow embed this `PYTHONHOME` variable while building python so that user don't have to manually set it? Or there is some other solution to it?
I have tried following, but this doesn't help:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=/opt/install38 --exec-prefix=/opt/install38 LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,../lib"
```

I guess the issue revolves around setting `PYTHONHOME` variable.

Comment: When you run `ldd /opt/install38/bin/python3` does it point to `/opt/install38/lib/python3*so`?

Comment: @alvits nope. It doesn't point to any python3*so.

Comment: `libpython3.8.so.1.0 => not found`